# Distinguish users Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am working in a website with codeigniter where we will have two different users.

In my database they are distinguished with a column so we have users 0 or 1
my question is how can i make a page only available for one kind of users?

If I am logged in as user 0 and I write the url to a page only for users 1 i can still acces it and i want to avoid it i have sessions so if you write the url and you are not logged in it redirects you to the log in page.

I have tried this in the controler but it does not work.

```
if(!($this->session->userdata('isloggedin'))&& ($this->session->userdata('patient')!= 1)){
        redirect('/Login/showLogin');
    }
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing??

Comment: I have to types of user 1 and 0 and i want to make some pages only available for one kind of user.
 
Right now, If I am user 1 i can go to user 0 pages by writing the url in the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to show the list of users to user type 1, you can do like this,

Store the user_type in session(1 or 0)

```
if($this->session->userdata("user_type") == 1){

} else {
    // display as no access
}
```